# Splitting a column into 3 columns in CSV file, PHP, multidimensional array

Tags: php, regex, csv

I've got a tough task to do I think.

I have a list of products, each and every single one has a specific column which I need to split into 3 columns if they're matching my string

```
foreach ($csv as $column){
    $match = preg_match("/(?:\d{3}\/\d{2}[R]\d{2})/", $column[5], $matches);
if ($match){
    $split = preg_split("/(?=R)|\//", $matches[0]);
           }
}
```

So, this is a multidimensional array, first array is a product and inside of each one are its details, which have 18 columns.

What I want to do is extending the array up to 21 columns and only insert split data (if is correct with my string) into column[6][7][8]

if the preg_match isn't correct, just leave [6][7][8] blank and don't touch the [5] column

So:

```
if !$match
[5] => 150/50ZR40
[6] => empty
[7] => empty
[8] => empty

if $match
[5] => 150/50R40
[6] => 150
[7] => 50
[8] => R40
```

The [6][7][8] columns already contain different data, so I need to move them further, from 6->9, 7->10 and 8->11 and everything else up to 18->21

edit: the csv is ; separated

Comment: A sample input and output is expected.

Comment: @revo edited post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this code is what you are looking for but it will give you an insight into what you may want to do things. Add capturing groups to your regex:

```
^(\d{3})/(\d{2})(R\d{2})$
```

and do a `preg_match` on it. On `TRUE` assign values to columns:

```
if (preg_match("~^(\d{3})/(\d{2})(R\d{2})$~", $column[5], $matches)) {
    /* $matches[0] will contain `150/50R40` */
    array_shift($matches); // removes first element of $matches
    array_splice($column, 6, 0, $matches); // inserts at offset 6
} else {
    // what else you want
}
```

Comment: ok, looks like this will be helpful, but I'm not sure I understand entire regex provided by you, what's the difference if i may ask?  also, what about moving the rest of the array by three places so split column won't override data which is already inside?

Comment: Difference is capturing groups `(...)`. They store parts of match for later use. It doesn't split at all it matches only.

Comment: I must say that it solved my problem, but it overrides my records, which I was asking actually twice, how to resolve to problem. matches[1] goes into column[6] which actually contains data and I have no idea how to move column[6] -> column[9] etc up until the end, before splitting

Comment: Just assign it to column[9]? I don't have any idea what you mean about overriding. Do whatever you want with `$matches`.

Comment: The entire array has data from [0] up to [19]. splitting the [5] into [6][7][8] will overwrite the data which is already inside of those columns

Comment: @revo please see the OPs new question which was solved with array_splice(). You'll effectively need to "shift" elements with keys [6] through [18] to have new keys -> [9] through [21]. This will make way for the new (potentially empty) [6], [7], and [8] elements.

Comment: Thank you @mickmackusa for providing an insightful comment. Updated.

Comment: May I suggest that the splice comes after the condition block.  `if` makes loaded array and `else` makes empty array.

Comment: Feel free to edit the answer to whatever makes it more suitable. @mickmackusa

Comment: Have I insulted you?

Comment: No why? I appreciate your help. @mickmackusa